# Maven cannot find com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.1.0 in intellij

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea

I keep getting the below error when trying to run my app thru Maven.

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:8.1.4.v20120524:run (default-cli)
>   on project MoveOrder: Execution default-cli of goal
>   org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:8.1.4.v20120524:run failed:
>   Plugin org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:8.1.4.v20120524 or one of
>   its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find
>   com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.1.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
>   was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted
>   until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

I also added

```
<dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                            <version>11.1.0</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
```

near the bottom before the final `</plugin>` tag. I also created a lib folder under my webapp/WEB-INF folder and pasted over ojdbc6-11.1.0.jar file in there hoping it would solve the issue, but it does not.

Here is my pom.xml file. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.wwt.moveorder</groupId>
    <artifactId>MoveOrder</artifactId>
    <name>MoveOrderUI</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>webbuild</id>
            <name>Local Nexus</name>
            <url>http://prodcit01.wwt.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/public</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>security</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Spring-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.transaction</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache POI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nu.xom</groupId>
            <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Oracle driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            net.alchim31.maven
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            yuicompressor-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.3.0,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>compress</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute></execute>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>MoveOrderUI</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>weblogic-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <name>${project.name}</name>
                    <adminServerHostName>devjas1.wwt.com</adminServerHostName>
                    <adminServerPort>7001</adminServerPort>
                    <adminServerProtocol>t3</adminServerProtocol>
                    <userId>shenoys</userId>
                    <password>pass123</password>
                    <upload>false</upload>
                    <remote>true</remote>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                    <debug>false</debug>
                    <targetNames>WWTServer1</targetNames>
                    <noExit>true</noExit>
                    <artifactPath>${project.build.directory}/${project.name}.war</artifactPath>
                    <noExit>true</noExit>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>weblogic</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wlfullclient</artifactId>
                        <version>10.3.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>weblogic</groupId>
                        <artifactId>webservices</artifactId>
                        <version>10.3.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>weblogic</groupId>
                        <artifactId>com.bea.core.descriptor.wl</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.0.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>${project.name}</warName>
                    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.name}</webappDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compress</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.name}</webappDirectory>
                    <aggregations>
                        <aggregation>
                            <removeIncluded>true</removeIncluded>
                            <output>${project.build.directory}/${project.name}/resources/js/app.js</output>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*-min.js</include>
                            </includes>
                        </aggregation>
                        <aggregation>
                            <removeIncluded>true</removeIncluded>
                            <output>${project.build.directory}/${project.name}/resources/css/app.css</output>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*-min.css</include>
                            </includes>
                        </aggregation>
                    </aggregations>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.4.v20120524</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>1</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>8089</stopPort>
                    <webApp>
                        <contextPath>/MoveOrderUI</contextPath>
                    </webApp>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>jetty.port</name>
                            <value>9900</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>userName</name>
                            <value>hummela</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                        <version>11.1.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the jdbc driver is marked as a `provided` dependency. Remove the `<scope>provided</scope>` and undo all the other hacks you mentioned and things should work just fine.

Provided dependencies should be made available by the container, rather than mentioned explicitly on the classpath. In this case I'm guessing that your container doesn't have the relevant library, so if you remove the scope maven should be able to manage the dependency like all the others and it should just work.

In general, the only scope you should use is `test`. `Provided`, in particular, is insidious and should be avoided. You can remove the `compile` scope lines too. You might want to keep the servlet dependency as provided, but I wouldn't.